# You have reached your question limit

Tags: support, asking-questions

I tried to post but got this. I could find nothing on it in the Help Center. What does it mean?

"You have reached your question limit"

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Comment: From the help page: https://askubuntu.com/help/question-bans

Comment: @MarkKirby well he has actually an overall positive score, so I don't think it is a question ban, my guess it is more rate limiting issue. but maybe a mod can shed any insight here. For me it is now as well hard to see if he has many deleted questions with a negative score.

Comment: I have not exceeded the limits that I found. ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Five hours ago from this post (so about when you posted here on Meta), you were stuck behind a question-asking ban.  The exact reason for this ban is never clear (not even to us moderators), because it uses some 'secret algorithm' that it uses to determine if you're banned from posting questions or not that is not disclosed, and has a mostly-unknown rate-limiting system (that is partially explained in the [Complete Rate-Limiting Guide over on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide))

Given that you got the "You have reached your question limit" error message, my *assumption* is that you tripped one of the reasons [stated in the Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) in the Asking section.  However, there's no way for us to tell.

The system *now* shows that you should be able to post questions again.  Keep in mind that if you have a number of new open questions you've made within a short period of time (even within a day) you might hit this rate-limiting system.

Comment: This may have been the case.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Users with < 125 rep, 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network

Comment: @fixit7 Possibly.  However, you aren't blocked now, so you should be OK so long as you respect the limits.